# jQuery slideUp, slideDown, addClass, & removeClass issues with multiple elements with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have divs(.details) that I want hidden until clicked(.aro). And if any other divs(.details) are visible, they need to close before showing the one clicked on. Hope that makes sense. Now, my code works OK. The only problem I have is if you click on the div class "aro" that is already showing the div "details", it slides up and then back down again. NOT GOOD! Can anyone help me with this? What I really want is: 1. When "aro" is clicked, show the contained "details" while hiding all other "details." 2. If you click on "aro" that already has "details" showing, not close anything. Not sure if this requires and if/else statement or what. If anyone can help, I'd be most appreciative. If you can help, would you explain your answer; even if slightly. Thanks!

HTML Code:

```
<div class="aro">
  <h2>One</h2>
  <div class="details">
    <p>I'm visible!</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="aro">
  <h2>Two</h2>
  <div class="details">
    <p>I'm visible!</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="aro">
  <h2>Three</h2>
  <div class="details">
    <p>I'm visible!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$(".aro").click(function () {
  $(".aro").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $(".aro .details").slideUp("slow");
  $(this).children(".details").slideDown("slow");
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2KpGc/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to check to see if the div already has the class "active".

```
$(".aro").click(function () {
  if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) { // If clicked div doesn't have class "active"
    $(".active .details").slideUp("slow"); // Moved for smoother slide animations
    $(".aro").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    //$(".aro .details").slideUp("slow");
    $(this).children(".details").slideDown("slow");
  }
});
```

should work.

Comment: That worked! Thank you. Figured it was a simple solution. But, I'm a newbie.

Comment: you could use `.toggle("slow");` instead of using `.slideUp("slow");` and `.slideDown("slow");`